# Finding the limit of $ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{2^k + 1}{2^{k-1} + 3}\right) $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{2^k + 1}{2^{k-1} + 3}\right) $$

I'm trying to prove that the limit of the sequence is $2$ using the squeeze theorem, but with no success.
Thanks

Comment: Is $k$ a constant? If so, since the fraction in the parenthesis does not depend on $n$, the limit can only be $0$, $1$ or $\infty$, never $2$

Comment: Sorry , I miss wrote the sequence , fixed it.

Comment: Try multiplying both numerator and denominator by $2^{-(k-1)}$.

Comment: I cant see how it helps can you elaborate ?.

Comment: Then you did the multiplication wrong. You should get $\frac{2+1/2^{k-1}}{1+3/2^{k-1}}$.

Comment: Oh thanks , now I see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Multiply the fraction by $1$ in the carefully chosen disguise

$$\frac{1/2^{k-1}}{1/2^{k-1}}\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

since $$2^n + a \sim 2^n $$ $\forall n, a$ we have

$$\frac{2^{k} + 1}{2^{k-1} + 3} = \frac{2^k}{2^{k-1}} = 2$$